# dropbox onchange with jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to get a onselect and then javascript function but it doesn't work.
It only works when I take away jquery-ui script, but then I get ugly forms.

```
<select id="productkleur" style="width: 200px;" onchange="productkleurchange()" data-theme="c" data-native-menu="true">
<option value="1" id="1">Zwart</option>
<option value="2" id="2">Rood</option>
<option value="3" id="3">Groen</option>
<option value="4" id="4">Paars</option>
<option value="5" id="5">Blauw</option>
<option value="6" id="6">Geel</option>
</select>
```

I tried this:

```
$("#productkleur").combobox({ 
        select: function (event, ui) { 
            alert("the select event has fired!"); 
            var productid = $("#productid").val();                                                                                 
var kleur = $("#productkleur").val();
var voorraad =  $("#productcolourstock").val();
var what =  "add";
console.log("change "+kleur+" to "+productid+" stock "+voorraad);
        } 
    }
);
```

I tried this

```
function productkleurchange() { 
var productid = $("#productid").val();                                                                                 
var kleur = $("#productkleur").val();
var voorraad =  $("#productcolourstock").val();
var what =  "add";
console.log("change "+kleur+" to "+productid+" stock "+voorraad);

};
```

The last one works fine when I remove jquery-ui, but when I don't nothing happens.

Anyone knows why or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the working code using jquery

```
$( "#productkleur" ).change(function() { 

var productid = $("#productid").val();                                                                                 
var kleur = $("#productkleur").val();
var voorraad =  $("#productcolourstock").val();
var what =  "add";
console.log("change "+kleur+" to "+productid+" stock "+voorraad);
});
```

Remove onchange="productkleurchange()" from the HTML before trying with the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `onChange` event in `select' it should work.

```
<select id="productkleur" style="width: 200px;" data-theme="c" data-native-menu="true">
<option value="1" id="1">Zwart</option>
<option value="2" id="2">Rood</option>
<option value="3" id="3">Groen</option>
<option value="4" id="4">Paars</option>
<option value="5" id="5">Blauw</option>
<option value="6" id="6">Geel</option>
</select>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/mq7vz8f7/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Also try this,

```
$('#productkleur').on('change', function() {
    var productid = $("#productid").val();
    var kleur = $("#productkleur").val();
    var voorraad = $("#productcolourstock").val();
    var what = "add";
    console.log("change " + kleur + " to " + productid + " stock " + voorraad);
});
```